# Converting byte array to hexadecimal value using BitConverter class in c#?

Tags: c#, bitconverter

I'm trying to convert a `byte array` into `hexadecimal` value using [Bitconverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

```
long hexValue = 0X780B13436587;
byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes ( hexValue );
string hexResult = BitConverter.ToString ( byteArray );
```

now if I execute the above code line by line, this is what I see

[image]

I thought **hexResult** string would be same as **hexValue** (i.e. 780B13436587h) but what I get is different, am I missing something, correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: The "fix" is to reverse your byte array (look carefully, your result is the value of the long backwards). The reason is due to endianness.

Comment: Excellent... Thanks for waking me up... Is there any method to get back to right order? I'm just curious to know, why is it reversed, any reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Endianness.

`BitConverter` uses CPU-endianness, which for most people means: little-endian. When *humans* write numbers, we tend to write big-endian (broadly speaking: you write the thousands, then hundreds, then tens, then the digits). For a CPU, big-endian means that the most-significant byte is *first* and the least-significant byte is *last*. However, unless you're using an Itanium, your CPU is probably little-endian, which means that the most-significant byte is **last**, and the least-significant byte is **first**. The CPU is implemented such that this **doesn't matter** unless you are peeking inside raw memory - it will ensure that numeric and binary arithmetic still works the way you expect. However, `BitConverter` *works* by peeking inside raw memory - hence you see the reversed data.

If you want the value in big-endian format, then you'll need to:

- do it manually in big-endian order
- check the `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` value, and if `true`:

  - either reverse the input bytes
  - or reverse the output

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely, the bytes in the output from BitConverter are reversed.

To get the hex-string for a number, you use the Convert class:

```
Convert.ToString(hexValue, 16);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of using Conver.Tostring(), but I was trying to use BitConverter class.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same number but reversed.

BitConverter.ToString can return string representation in reversed order:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97(v=vs.110).aspx

"All the elements of value are converted. The order of hexadecimal strings returned by the ToString method depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or big-endian."

Comment: I wonder why that method has the same endianness disclaimer as the others. After all, this method just receives an array of bytes - it's nothing to do with this method whether the bytes come from a big-endian int, or a little-endian int, or something else entirely.

Comment: @Rawling you are misunderstanding; it is **entirely** processing the bytes in the order they exist. The problem is that the `long` with value `0X780B13436587` **is** the bytes 87 65 43 13 0B 78 00 00 - *precisely because* your CPU is little endian.

Comment: @MarcGravell That is exactly my point. It is entirely up to the `BitConverter.GetBytes()` method you called *earlier* what bytes you have - or you may have bytes from *anywhere*. The `BitConverter.ToString` method is entirely *unaffected* by the endianness of the system it runs on. So why does [its MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) say *"The order of hexadecimal strings returned by the ToString method depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or big-endian."*?